# I want to convert bytes to IP and PORT

Tags: python, networking, hex, ip, byte

I want to convert a hexadecimal byte variable that comes in through the network into IP and Port.

For example, the format is :

```
value = (b'\xd3[\xdf\x94:\x98\xd5\xe6J\x9f\xb2\xfb\xd8\x18\xbdDsa')
# Size is random but multiples of 6 all.

type(value) # bytes
```

I want to print the variable named value above as follows.

```
>>> func(value)
"211.91.223.148:15000"
"213.230.74.159:45819"
```

Even if I searched, I could not find a module that changes bytes to IP and Port.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you now the actual value of your example?

Comment: Also, do you know the encoding?

Comment: Any documentation how exactly ip and port are encoded as bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**test.py:**

```
import ipaddress
import struct

from itertools import islice


N = 6


def func(value):
    it = iter(value)

    while chunk := bytes(islice(it, N)):
        ip, port = struct.unpack("!IH", chunk)
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(ip)

        print(f"{ip}:{port}")


def main():
    value = b"\xd3[\xdf\x94:\x98\xd5\xe6J\x9f\xb2\xfb\xd8\x18\xbdDsa"
    func(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
211.91.223.148:15000
213.230.74.159:45819
216.24.189.68:29537
```